# this.router.navaigate not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i am working on angular 4 app and trying to navigate from module component to layout component when button clicked. but navigate not working.

and i don't see any error message.

i spent lot of time on google to resolve this issue but i am unable to resolve.

below is the code.

**html:**

```
      <div class="land-item" (click)="qualityrd()">      
      <h3>QAULITY</h3>
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"  style="color:blue"></i>
      <div class="over-item">
```

**component**

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { Router ,ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router'

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-module-selector',
          templateUrl: './module-selector.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['../css/style.css','../css/responsive.css']
        })
        export class ModuleSelectorComponent  {

          constructor(
                      private _router:Router,private route: ActivatedRoute  ) { }


          qualityrd():void
          {
            this._router.navigate(['/QualityLayout'], { relativeTo: this.route });
          }

        }
```

**Layout Component**

```
            import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component ({  

       selector: 'my-app',  
       templateUrl:'./Layout.html',
       styleUrls:['../css/footer.css']

    })  
    export class LayoutComponent {  
        isIn = false;   // store state
        toggleState() { // click handler
            let bool = this.isIn;
            this.isIn = bool === false ? true : false; 
        }
    }
```

and finally my app module

```
                import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { CommonModule }    from '@angular/common';

        import { FormsModule, FormGroup,FormControl,Validators,FormBuilder,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 

        import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
        import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
        import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
        import {LayoutComponent} from './Layout/Layout.Component';
        import {ExcelDownloadComponent} from './ExcelDownload/ExcelDownload.Component';
        import {ExcelUploadComponent} from './ExcelUpload/ExcelUpload.Component';
        import {SpotCheckStatusComponent} from './spotCheck/spotcheckstatus.component';
        import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './others/PageNotFoundComponent';
        import {  Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { FileSelectDirective, FileDropDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload';
        import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
        import { ModuleSelectorComponent } from './module-selector/module-selector.component';


        const appRoutes: Routes = [
          { path: 'SPOTCHECK', component: SpotCheckStatusComponent },
          { path: 'ExcelDownalod', component: ExcelDownloadComponent },
          { path: 'ExcelUpload', component: ExcelUploadComponent },
          { path: 'ModuleSelector', component: ModuleSelectorComponent },
          { path: 'QualityLayout', component: LayoutComponent },
          { path: '', redirectTo:'/ModuleSelector' ,pathMatch:'full' },
          { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent } 
        ];


        @NgModule({
          declarations:[ AppComponent,SpotCheckStatusComponent,PageNotFoundComponent,LayoutComponent,
            ExcelDownloadComponent,ExcelUploadComponent,ExcelDownloadComponent
            ,FileDropDirective, FileSelectDirective, ModuleSelectorComponent ],
          imports:    [ BrowserModule , FormsModule,HttpModule,ReactiveFormsModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
          providers: [],
          bootstrap: [ModuleSelectorComponent]


        })
        export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: not working means ..navigation not working and i clearly mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
{ relativeTo: this.route }
```

it needs to be relative to the root, which you achieve by prefixing the path with `/`

```
['/QualityLayout']
```

is a valid absolute path, no need to make it relative to a route.

Comment: yes i removed { relativeTo: this.route } but not working